# How can I count the frequency of a variable in R?

Tags: r, count

I am currently trying to count the frequency of countries that appear in a dataframe object.

I tried using `count` commands as well as `rle(sort(x))`, which apparently is used to search for strings. But it does not seem to yield any results.

```
rle(sort(x))
```

I tried using this, but does not seem to work. I also tried to use

```
count(x, "COUNTRY")
```

but all it does is count how many entries are there.

How can I get a result such as:

```
      Country        Frequency
[1]   United States      3
[2]   Mexico             5
[3]   Germany            12
```

Comment: table( x$COUNTRY)

Comment: or: summary(factor(x$COUNTRY))

Comment: dplyr uses NSE, so you'll need to pass the column name unquoted i.e. `dplyr::count(x, COUNTRY)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example using `dplyr` and the built-in dataset `mtcars`:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  count(cyl)
```

or

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  add_count(cyl)
```

Answer (score 1):

other solution is:      table(yourdataframe$x)

Answer (score 1):

count(x,Country,Frequency)

Have to include both to see a deeper breakdown then it'll count the countries and Frequency

or

X%>%group_by(Country)%>%summarise(sum = sum(Frequency), n = n())